# multiple plots in each loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, plot, figure

I want to plot 2 graphs in each loop so that they will appear in two separate figures, with consecutive number order. I mean:  first looping: `figure 1`, `figure 2`, second looping: `figure 3`, `figure 4` and so on. How do I achieve that? I tried to make the code as follows,

```
for i = 1:3 
figure(i)
plot something

figure(i+1)
plot something else
```

but I get the order as : `figure(1)`, `figure(2)`, `figure(2)`, `figure(3)`, `figure(3)`, `figure(4)` !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

```
for k=1:3 % don't use i as a variable
    figure(2*k-1)
    % Plot some stuff
    figure(2*k)
    % Plot some more stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be this:

```
for i = 1:3 
 figure(2*i-1)
 plot something

 figure(2*i)
 plot something else
end
```